# Optical Flow under very low-contrast and very low-texture

Tags: opencv, image-processing

The frames are captured from bottom-forward camera.
The distance between camera and plane is very short. about 10cm.
The camera moves and rotate. I have to track trajectory of this camera from frames.
So I want to get affine transform.

I did experiments with adaptive histogram equal.

The dense optical flow and Lukas Kanade method do not give good results.

What is the best method to track trajectory of camera under low-contrast and low-texture?

Comment: are you able to find some per-image-correspondences manually by looking at the images? Can you give an example of challenging images? Did you try keypoint matching (SIFT / ORB)? Are there any usable assumptions about maximum motion between two frames? Any assumptions about limited camera/object rotation between two frames?

Comment: I tried but I can not find any features of ORB, BRISK, KAZE, AKAZE, SURF, SIFT,FAST because of very low-texture.

Comment: can you show sample images? Are you as a human able to see correspondences between two frames?

Comment: simple stuff like block matching might work, but you will need a lot of assumptions and limited possible motion between two frames and unclear whether it can be fast enough in the end. You might have to find some "points of interest" with blob detection or thresholding or whatever is still available in your "very low texture". If there is nothing left in the "very low texture" you can't track the motion visually.

Comment: Yes , I am able to see changes between two frames.

Comment: Do you think is it possible?

Comment: I cant access those files

Comment: Thank you for your help. You can download it with clicking ダウンロード button below of site.

Comment: video ([snapshot](https://i.imgur.com/e67YN0V.jpg)) is **out of focus**. and grainy because there's not enough lighting. why won't you adjust the focus?